# What is the best way to handle CRSs in Geopandas so that both versions <0.7 and >=0.7 are handled?

Tags: python, geopandas, pyproj, compatibility

I am developing a python package called [RivGraph](https://github.com/jonschwenk/RivGraph). I've recently run into an issue related to geopandas' decision to overhaul CRS representation, as described [here](https://jorisvandenbossche.github.io/blog/2020/02/11/geopandas-pyproj-crs/) and [here](https://geopandas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/projections.html#upgrading-to-geopandas-0-7-with-pyproj-2-2-and-proj-6). The short of it is that in geopandas versions <0.7, crs's were stored as dictionaries of proj4 strings, e.g. `{'init':'epsg:4326'}`. In geopandas 0.7 and moving forward, crs's are stored as pyproj objects, which are richer and more robust. Ok, great.

I share RivGraph as a [conda-installable](https://anaconda.org/jschwenk/rivgraph), and direct people to install it using conda to ensure all the dependencies are worked out. What I've discovered is that, depending on the user's platform, sometimes geopandas <0.7 is installed, and sometimes geopandas 0.7 is installed. So that leads me to ask this question:

**What is the best way to make my package compatible with both of these versions of geopandas?** I guess I realize that I can check the geopandas version in my package, and write `if` statements that use one syntax vs. the other, but this seems tedious and ugly. I can't quite figure out if there is a single syntax that is compatible across both versions of geopandas when it comes to crs management.

Comment: Not an answer since I'm suggesting you don't try to support both when you're developing a new package, but you could specify geopandas >= 0.7 in your [package requirements](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/latest/resources/define-metadata.html#run).  Conda environments are disposable and it's easy to just `conda create` a new environment with an up to date geopandas if users get conflicts trying to install your package in an existing environment.

Comment: I generally agree, but the issue is that I developed most of my package before 0.7 existed, so it already has full support for <0.7. Not sure if it makes sense to strip that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to pin your package to >=0.7. Otherwise, here is a guide for you: https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/crs_compatibility.html#geopandas

Comment: Reposting a comment from above: I generally agree, but the issue is that I developed most of my package before 0.7 existed, so it already has full support for <0.7. Not sure if it makes sense to strip that out and replace with 0.7 syntax. That's why I was hoping for a single solution for both versions.

Comment: Makes sense. Did the link above answer your question?

Comment: I guess so. It looks like the version check is unavoidable, so I guess that's the answer. The other thing is that pyproj < v2 is sometimes installed as well, which has a different syntax compared with >v2 as well. It looks like the best thing to do is to pin to >=0.7 to avoid both issues.